# How to avoid string getting flipped while card is rotated

Tags: jquery, css

Here while rotating the card the text is getting flipped, is there any way to fix it. I thought of using reverse() method but the text is up side down. please help me. I have used jQuery hover() method with two functions.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.card{
background-color:lightblue;
color:green;
line-height:70px;
text-align:center;
padding:10px;
width:100px;
height:100px;
transition: all 0.6s ease;
transform-style:preserve-3d;
border-radius:10px;
border:2px solid gray;
}
.card:hover{
transform:rotateZ(180deg);
background-color:orange;
color:purple;
direction:rtl;
}
.card-container{
perspective:1000px;
padding:10px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class='container'>

    <div class='card-container'>
        <div class='card'> 
            <div class='front'>TEXT</div>
            <div class='back'></div>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
<script src='jquery.js'></script>
<script>

$(function(){
$('ul.parent >li').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('ul.child').show(200);
},function(){
    $(this).find('ul.child').hide(200);
});
});
//card hover and rotate
$('.card').hover(
function(){
$(this).find('.front').text('');
$(this).find('.back').text(('HELLO')); //hello is reversed when flipped <-----
},
function(){
$(this).find('.back').text('');
$(this).find('.front').text('TEXT');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Working as expected, see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FPCRb/2240/)

Answer (score 0):

Apply a negative rotation to the text, 
It will appear like the text isn't rotating

```
.card:hover .front{
  transform:rotateZ(-180deg);
}

.card .front{
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FPCRb/2241/ (kudos to [Bhushan Kawadkar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/649504/bhushan-kawadkar) for the js-fiddle)

Note that the rotation is done through CSS code, there is no need for JS/jquery.

The `.card:hover` rule will apply the transformation rule once your mouse hovers over the card. `rotateZ(180deg)` will rotate the entire element 180 degrees, including the textual content. In order to stop this from happening, we can apply a negative rotation to *just* the text element. this is achieved by adding the `.card:hover .front` rule.